# dynamics of simple recurrent network on very simple test set

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network, forecasting

I'm trying to understand how RNN work. I use a little example:
Let's say I want to predict the consumption of electricity of my building.

The input is 1 week of consumption and I want the output to be the predicted consumption for the day after, hour by hour i.e. consumption at midnight, consumption at 1 hour etc.

For simulation and simplicity, I use a very simple consumption function : c(h)=h where h is the hour of the day and c(h) is the consumption for this hour, here identity. Hence, the consumption for 1 day is ```[0, 1, 2,..., 23, 24]
I use the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

matplotlib.use('TKAgg')

Inputs = np.tile(np.arange(24), (7)).reshape(1, 7*24, 1)
Outputs = np.arange(24).reshape(1, 24, 1)

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(layers.LSTM(32, # 32 is choosen at random
                      input_shape=(7*24, Inputs.shape[-1])
                       ))
model2.add(layers.Dense(24, activation='linear'))
model2.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
history = model2.fit(x=Inputs, y=Outputs, epochs=200,
                    batch_size= 1,
                    validation_data = (Inputs, Outputs))
plt.figure()
plt.ylim([0, 24])
plt.xlim([0, 24])
y = model2(Inputs, training=False)
plt.plot(y[0])
plt.show()
```

Which gives the figure below (the optimal should be the identity):
[image: learning identity]

I can see (I've other tests) that the first hours of the day (i.e. the first values of the training set) are learned first: the curve is linear up to 5 and then bang, nothing is learned. When I increment de number of epochs, the linear part increases. And when I change the first hour of the day to 5, the curve become linear at 5.
The question is : **WHY** ?

My guess is that the first hours are presented first. The first hour is presented first, the error is calculated, the weights modified. The the 2nd hour is presented along with the first output (recurrent connection), the error calculated and the weights modified etc. So the first hour is taken into account during all the steps of the learning. The second hour is taken into account during n-1 steps etc. But I find the difference between the almost perfect part of the curve at the beginning and the end of it very important. May be too important for my explanation. Am'I wrong ?

Comment: `model2.add(layers.Dense(24, activation='linear'))`
why you're using the linear activation

Comment: In my understanding, the dense layer is mainly used to reduce the size of the output from 32 to 24. Since the values are not normalized, the choice is quite reduced. I've tried relu and selu and the behavior is the same...